# Why do these rectangles sometimes show that they are colliding even though they are not?

Tags: java, processing, collision-detection, rectangles

When I run the code it generates 16 rectangles with a random size, random position, and a random color. It is then supposed to turn white if it is colliding with another rectangle. Most of the time it works fine but every so often rectangles turn white when they are not colliding with anything.

[image: Example of code not working correctly]

**Main**

```
int boxCount = 16;
Box[] boxes = new Box[boxCount];

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);

  for(int i = 0; i < boxCount; i++){
    boxes[i] = new Box(random(50, width - 50), random(50, height - 50), random(20, 50), random(20, 50), color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255)));
  }
}

void draw(){
  for(int i = 0; i < boxCount; i++){
    boxes[i].create();
    for(int x = 0; x < boxCount; x++){
      if(boxes[i] != boxes[x]){
        boxes[i].collide(boxes[x]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Class**

```
class Box{
  float x;
  float y;
  float w;
  float h;
  color c;

  Box(float _x, float _y, float _w, float _h, color _c){
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    w = _w;
    h = _h;
    c = _c;
  }

  void create(){
    fill(c);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
  }

  void collide(Box o){
    float right = x + (w / 2);
    float left = x - (w / 2);
    float top = y - (h / 2);
    float bottom = y + (h / 2);

    float oRight = o.x + (o.w / 2);
    float oLeft = o.x - (o.w / 2);
    float oTop = o.y - (o.h / 2);
    float oBottom = o.y + (o.h / 2);

    if(right > oLeft && left < oRight && bottom > oTop && top < oBottom){
      c = color(255, 255, 255);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`rect`](https://processing.org/reference/rect_.html) doesn't draw a rectangle around center point, by default the rectangle is drawn at a top left position (`x`, `y`) with a size (`with`, `height`).

You've 2 possibilities to solve the issue:

Either change the collision detection method:

```java
class Box{

    // [...]

    void collide(Box o){    
        if(x < o.x+o.w  && o.x < x+w && y < o.y+o.h && o.y < y+h){
            c = color(255, 255, 255);
        }
    }
}
```

**Or** set the `CENTER` [`rectMode()`](https://processing.org/reference/rectMode_.html), which will cause the rectangle to be drawn as you expect it:

```java
class Box{

    // [...]

    void create(){
        fill(c);
        rectMode(CENTER);
        rect(x, y, w, h);
    }

    // [...]
}
```